# Code wars: Flap Display with while loops

Tags: ruby, loops, hash, while-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying to work through a level 5 kata by using while loops. Essentially the problem is to turn each letter rotors[n] number of times and then move on to the next rotors number until you get an output word.

```
flap_display(["CAT"],[1,13,27])
```

should output `["DOG"]`

Here's what I have so far

```
  def flap_display(lines, rotors)
    stuff = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ?!@#&()|<>.:=-+*/0123456789"
    i = 0 
    j = 0  
    new_word = lines
    while i < rotors.length 
      while j < new_word[0].length 
        new_word[0][j] = stuff[stuff.index(new_word[0][j]) + rotors[i]]
        j += 1 
      end 
      i += 1 
      j = 0 
    end
    new_word
  end
```

This technically traverses the stuff string and assigns the right letters. However it fails two important things: it does not skip each letter when it rotates to the correct position (C should stop rotating when it hits D, A when it hits O etc) and it does not account for reaching the end of the stuff list and eventually returns a nil value for `stuff[stuff.index(new_word[0][j]) + rotors[i]]`. How can I fix these two problems using basic loops and enumerables or maybe a hash?

Comment: A fuller statement of the problem is given [here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/airport-arrivals-slash-departures-number-1/javascript).

Comment: Interesting. I would have thought you pass the target word and use that to calculate the rotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fuller statement of the problem is given [here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/airport-arrivals-slash-departures-number-1/javascript). This is one Ruby-like way it could be done.

```
FLAPS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ?!@#&()|<>.:=-+*/0123456789"
NBR_FLAPS = FLAPS.size

def flap_display(str, rot)
  rot_cum = rot.each_with_object([]) { |n,a| a << a.last.to_i + n }   
  str.gsub(/./) { |c| FLAPS[(c.ord + rot_cum.shift - 65) % NBR_FLAPS] }
end

flap_display("CAT", [1,13,27])
  #=> "DOG"
flap_display("DOG", [-1,-13,-27])
  #=> "CAT"
flap_display("CAT", [5,37,24])
  #=> "H*&"
```

`'A'.ord #=> 65` and `rot_cum` contains the cumulative values of `rot`:

```
arr = [1, 13, 27]
rot_cum = arr.each_with_object([]) { |n,a| a << a.last.to_i + n }   
  #=> [1, 14, 41]
```

I've written `a.last.to_i` rather than `a.last` to deal with the case where `a` is empty, so `a.last #=> nil`, meaning `a.last.to_i => nil.to_i => 0`. See [NilClass#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/NilClass.html#method-i-to_i). Those opposed to such trickery could write:

```
rot_cum = arr.drop(1).each_with_object([arr.first]) { |n,a| a << a.last + n }
```

Comment: this makes so much more sense. I was trying to traverse the entire FLAPS string each time I did a pass through and stop flapping one letter as it hit the right place. However the idea that each successive flap will just flap by the previous rot values plus the current rot value allows me to better understand how it works.

What elements is the gsub(/./) replacing?

Comment: dan, the regular expression `r = /./` in `str.gsub(r)` matches every character of `str`, because `.` matches any character. The block variable `c` in the block is therefore successively set equal to each character in `str`.